# Migrating over content types in content type hub

Tags: content-type-hub

I have a content type hub that i have migrated some content types over too. Yet the site collections do not have the content types in, even after running the timer jobs. Do i have to force publish them?

Answer (score 0):

- Goto Site Settings-> Site Content Types and see if the Content Types are in published state. Select Publish and click on OK to publish the  CT.
  [image]
- Now Go to Central Administration → Monitoring → Timer Job Definitions
  Open the **Content Type Hub Job Definition**.
  Press the Run Now button.
  Go back to the Timer Job Definitions.
  Open the **Content Type Subscriber Job** definitions for each of your Web 
  Applications and press their Run Now buttons.

[Additional Reference](http://morg.nl/2011/11/content-type-hub-not-working-possible-causes/)